Charge a 3S (12.6V) LiPo battery with a 6V solar panel
I'm trying to charge a 3S LiPo (11.1V) battery with a 6V solar panel. Ideally, I would like to find off-the-shelf components to achieve this functionality efficiently.
Background:

I've been searching for an MPPT charge controller that can handle a multi-cell LiPo battery, but most MPPT controllers I found seem to be designed for 1S LiPo batteries.
I tried to create a solution using the following setup:

6V Solar Panel connected to an MPPT controller designed for a 1S LiPo battery (MPPT-SD05CRMA Solar Charge Controller).
The output from the MPPT connected to a DC-DC boost converter (DC-DC 1.5A Step-Up Boost Converter) to step up the voltage to charge the 3S LiPo battery.



Problem:

When connecting the components in the above configuration, the charging current flowing into a partially charged battery (around 11.3V) drops to approximately 30mA, despite the solar panel being capable of supplying much more current.
Depending on the order in which I connected the solar panel, MPPT, boost converter, and battery, I sometimes observed a higher initial current (over 200mA), which then drops to 30mA.

I suspect that the MPPT might not recognize the boost converter as a correct load, or the boost converter's input impedance might vary and interfere with the MPPT's operation.
Questions:

Compatibility Issue: Is my suspicion correct that the MPPT controller and boost converter are not working well together? If so, can this issue be mitigated by using a bidirectional buck/boost converter instead of a simple boost converter?

Alternative Setup: Is there an alternative setup or specific components you would recommend to efficiently charge a 3S LiPo battery from a 6V solar panel using MPPT technology?

BMS Integration: How can I integrate a Battery Management System (BMS) into this setup to ensure proper load balancing and protection during charging?


I came across a similar post discussing the interaction between solar panels, MPPT controllers, and DC-DC converters, but I'm specifically looking for advice on how to address this issue with a 3S LiPo setup.
Thanks in advance for any guidance or suggestions.

MPPT is all about matching impedances which is difficult starting up a boost conv,  Vmpt/Voc should be ~ 82% is your best bet. Add more panel voltage.

You don't appear to have a battery charger. This is not optional.

True, I do not have a battery charger integrated atm.
I would like to buy a small battery charger that can charge my 3S LiPo, but most boards seem to be only made for LiIon batteries, https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Aideepen-Lithium-Battery-Overcharge-Protection/dp/B08FY6TNWY/ref=sr_1_2
Afaik, these might work to charge a LiPo's cells, but are not ideally and might damage it. I don't care too much, if the LiPo looses capacity over time or needs replacement after a couple of cycles. I just don't want them to catch fire.

If you don't want them to catch fire use a battery charger.

Thanks, @Finbarr. Do you have any recommendations for a small, light-weight battery charger board that can be powered with a) my solar cells or b) with DC voltage?
